# Tkinter Button Number Cycle - Tkinter question

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

First question here...

Here is my code-

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Button: 0, 1 and 2.")

preset_numbers = cycle(["0", "1", "2"])

lbl = tk.Label(root, text = next(preset_numbers), width=20)
lbl.pack()

tk.Button(root, width = 20, command = lambda: lbl.config(text = next(preset_numbers))).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Im a bit confused on how I can make the button ITSELF display 0 1 2 and cycle through them instead of staying static...

Comment: After you create the button use `<tk.Button>.config(command=lambda: <tk.Button>.config(text=next(preset_numbers)))`

Comment: Don't use lambda. Instead, use a function. They are much easier to debug.

Comment: @TheLizzard Mind elaborating? I tried putting this in my code and it crashed it....

Comment: @komoc454 probably because You literally copied it

Answer (score 2):

You need to save a reference to the button so that you can call the `configure` method on it. Also, I strongly recommend using a proper function than `lambda`, as functions are easier to read and easier to debug.

```
def update_button():
    button.configure(text=next(preset_numbers))

button = tk.Button(root, width = 20, command = update_button)
button.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

If You wanted to have the button itself change text, this is a way to go, I guess:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Button: 0, 1 and 2.")

preset_numbers = cycle((1, 2, 3))

btn = tk.Button(root, text=next(preset_numbers), width=20, 
                command=lambda: btn.config(text=next(preset_numbers)))
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Few things to mention:

I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Also I suggest following PEP 8 and not having spaces around `=` IF it is a keyword argument

Comment: It's better to use `(0, 1, 2)` instead of `["0", "1", "2"]`. `tkinter` can deal with integers and creating a `tuple` is faster than a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Button: 0, 1 and 2.")

preset_numbers = cycle((0, 1, 2))

button = tk.Button(root, width=20, text=next(preset_numbers))
# Please note that the `button.pack()` is on its own line.
button.pack()

button.config(command=lambda: button.config(text=next(preset_numbers)))

root.mainloop()
```

It assigns the button to a variable named `button`. Then it calls `.config` on it to change it's command attribute. Also as @BryanOakley said, it will be much easier to debug if you use a function instead of a `lambda`.

---

EDIT:

An even easier method:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

def change_buttons_text():
    button.config(text=next(preset_numbers))

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Button: 0, 1 and 2.")

preset_numbers = cycle((0, 1, 2))

text = next(preset_numbers)
button = tk.Button(root, width=20, text=text, command=change_buttons_text)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

With this method the code looks better